# OxyPlot: Display labels for max/min values on LinearColorAxis

Tags: axis, oxyplot

I'm trying to display labels for maximum and minimum values on color axis.
I've created and LinearColorAxis object, set max and min values from result array.
Currenty max = 180, min = -180

```
var colorAxis = new LinearColorAxis();
colorAxis.Palette = result.GetPalette();
colorAxis.Position = AxisPosition.Right;
colorAxis.Maximum = result.Array.Max2D();
colorAxis.Minimum = result.Array.Min2D();
```

After that I can see the next graph:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFkma.png)

But as you can see there are no labels for min and max values. How can I do that? And need to display label for it to see my 180 and -180 values. Step for axis can be changed when I have other result with other min and max values. But I should display labels of min/max values for all cases.